# How can reference a field with same name without include alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query a litle bigger than this:

```
SELECT  ap.car_id, rs.car_id, ..... ap.*, rs.*
FROM    avl_pool  ap
JOIN    route_sources rs
 ON     ap.avl_id = rs.avl_id_begin
```

[image]

As you can see I get two columns named `car_id` with same value and doesnt have a problem. Dont understand why doesnt give me ambiguous error here.

I can do this and work ok:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT  ap.car_id, rs.car_id
      FROM    avl_pool  ap
      JOIN    route_sources rs
        ON     ap.avl_id = rs.avl_id_begin
     ) T
```

But this give me ambiguous `car_id`

```
SELECT car_id
FROM (
     SELECT  ap.car_id, rs.car_id
     FROM    avl_pool  ap
     JOIN    route_sources rs
      ON     ap.avl_id = rs.avl_id_begin
     ) T
```

Of course I could include alias on each field, but as I say there are lot of columns. So can I reference the column without include an alias? They have same value so dont really care which one use.

Comment: I believe in subquery or join you can't select [any column with such name]

Comment: check this: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4701.1100730185%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that column names in the `select`-part of a query do not need to be unique, but a any reference to a column (e.g. in an expression or another (sub)query) must not be ambiguous.

So the following statement is OK:

```
select id, somecolumn as id from test
--> OK.
```

However, the following query will not work, because a reference to a column named `id` cannot be unambiguously bound to either the first or the second column of the subquery:

```
select id from (select id, somecolumn as id from test) t2

--> "42702: column reference "id" is ambiguous"
```

Note that `select *...` will work, because then columns are not referred to by (possibly ambiguous) names:

```
select * from (select id, somecolumn as id from test) t2
--> OK.
```